# Ubuntu 11.10 randomly crashes to a screen full of numbers?

Tags: hardware

I'm very new to Ubuntu and only got it because I had the blue screen of death on Windows 7. Now it will randomly crash to a screen that looks like terminal with tons written on it? Is this because of my past problems or because of Ubuntu? How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's impossible to say with so little information. Try to provide everything you can about what you did and the exact error messages.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem with Windows 7 was probably a hardware related problem which is why it still shows up in Ubuntu.

I suggest you verify your memory with Memtest86+. You can see a great presentation on how to use Memtest86+ here: http://www2.corsair.com/training/how_to_memtest/

The presentation explains how to burn a ISO image on Windows 7 but on Ubuntu you can just burn it with Brasero and the rest of the presentation will work with any operating system.

You should also use the Ubuntu Disk Utility (found under System>Administration), click on SMART Data and then run a test for all of your hard drives.